# how run class with extends IntentService when onLocationChanged

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-intentservice

This is my IntentService Code. This class is called (inBackground):

```
package com.example.seadog.gps;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class inBackground extends IntentService {

    public inBackground() {
        super("GPSLocation");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        JSONObject json = GlobalConfig.Json;
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(json);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

}
```

When I try run this class when my location is changed in this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, inBackground.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 3000, pendingIntent);
```

then my app is immediately closed. Of course the above code I execute in onLocationChanged. What is wrong?

Comment: from the documentation: '''IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and **stops itself** when it runs out of work.'''

Comment: OK, I created new method in MainActivity. Now I call this method in onLocationChanged in this way: mActivity.sent(); and result is the same. My app is closed. How I can call a method in MainActivity from another classes?